Computing an integral over a Ball with center $a$
This question is related to the topic Showing $|x|^\alpha$ is an $A_p$ weight for $-d<\alpha<d(p-1)$
Question. How can compute it be  $\int_{B(a,R)}|x|^{\alpha}\,dx$ calculated?
My attempt:
\begin{align}
 \int_{B(a,R)}|x|^{\alpha}\,dx&=\int_{B(0,R)}|x+a|^{\alpha}\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{R}\int_{\partial B(x,s)}|x+a|^{\alpha}dS(x)ds\\
\end{align}
but, I don't know how to calculate $\int_{\partial B(x,s)}|x+a|^{\alpha}dS(x)$.
Thanks.

Do you need an exact value for the integral or is an upper/lower bound fine?

Ideally, the exact value (I don't know if this is difficult), but I think it is sufficient for me to have a good lower bound (non-negative).
